# How to remove Bluetooth from Android build?

Tags: android, linux, makefile, embedded

I am working with Android Open Source Project (AOSP) on an IMX based board. I would like to exclude the bluetooth modules from the compilation.

I used "mgrep" to look into the Makefiles to find references to the Bluetooth but I couldn't figure out which options I need to add or remove.

I would like to know which Makefiles and config files I would need to edit. How do I remove Bluetooth from Android build?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with packages/apps/Bluetooth (have not tested removing this before) although I'm not really sure that's enough if you mean to remove everything that relates to Bluetooth in the aosp tree (e.g. there are a number of classes in frameworks/base relating to Bluetooth as well).

There may also be a way to define your device or board makefiles to report that it doesn't support Bluetooth but I have not tinkered with that before either.